# Regulation if stop lamps may require an activated ignition or not

Tags: electrical, ignition, automotive-design, brake-light

Where can I find a regulation for Europe or Germany, if stop lamps may require an activated ignition or not?

I saw that the stop lamps of some cars are still fully functional without the ignition key in place. Other cars require that the key is turned to, the first position (ignition).

Comment: Key first position is usually acc ie accessories like radio.

Comment: Do you mean a new car? In UK when I started driving, stop lamps could be activated by the foot brake, with or without the general power switch (first position) but no longer can be on a modern car. I don't think the older cars are illegal though

Comment: @WeatherVane I expect there is a regulation xyz-2012 which requires that stop lights do no longer require to be switchable without ignition since 2012 for instance. I searched online, but could not find anything related. I want to know, if it is a bug if the stop lights do not work without ignition, or not.

Comment: For a particular vehicle, a wiring diagram could tell you if the brake light circuit is always hot, or hot on ign. Or, at the fuse panel, you could check if the brake light fuse is always hot, or only on ignition.